# XMLHttp GET request returns json objects, and undefined, how do I get rid of undefined?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I am getting the correct json objects in my GET Request, but I am also returned undefined after every request. Sometimes I am returned more than one undefined. How do I get rid of the undefined from showing up with my objects? Putting return in my get request function does nothing. Here is my code:

```
(function makeRequest2(){  
   url.forEach(function(e){
   let httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
   if(!httpRequest){
       alert('can not create http instance!')
       return false;
}
   httpRequest.onreadystatechange = streams;
   httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/' + e, true);
   httpRequest.send();
  console.log('test');
  }); 
  return true;
   })();

function streams(){
if(this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
  if(this.status === 200){
    let data = JSON.parse(this.response);
console.log(data.logo);

    } 
  }
}
```

The Data.logo returns the correct json object strings, but it also returns undefined, sometimes more than one undefined since I am getting multiple httprequests.

https://codepen.io/icewizard/pen/qpyZqa link to codepen

Comment: for which url are you getting undefined?

Comment: I am getting the correct json object for all the url's I request, but  at least one undefined appears after the json objects are shown after every request, sometimes more than one undefined is shown too, and they happen randomly on the url's.